# Using .replace() to change period to underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to replace a period in a string to an underscore using the javascript `.replace()` function. For example, if the string was `Project.Build`, I would want it to become `Project_Build`. Unfortunately, the method isn't currently doing that. The period continues to remain a period.

This line of code is trimming off all white space from the string. It is also replacing all spaces with underscores as well. This part is currently working.

```
var rowID = $.trim(new String(status.teamCityProject).toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_").replace(/\./g, '_')) + status.id;

$("tr#" + rowID + " td.status").html(status.status).css({ 'color': statusColor, 'font-weight': 'bolder' })
```

Comment: Regex seems ok, and it works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BDZWK/

Comment: Looks correct to me as well. Maybe `status.id` has a period in it?

Comment: Are you assigning it back to the orginal string... .replace will not change the original text.

Comment: @Vega you should post your comment as the answer :)

Comment: @Vega Winner winner, chicken dinner. I'd make that an answer as it seems most likely.

Comment: Also, `new String()` is superfluous for the reason Vega mentioned.  `.replace()` returns a new string.  JS strings are immutable.

Comment: I'm not assigning it back to the original string. Let me update the code to show what's happening.

Comment: haha will do :) Love you guys

Comment: @Vega Before trying to replace the period everything was working perfectly, but when I tried to replace that as I said nothing happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign or update the modified string to the var and use it.. `.replace` will not update the original text. (Also removed new String)

```
var rowID = $.trim(status.teamCityProject.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "_").replace(/\./g, '_')) + status.id;

$("tr#" + rowID + " td.status").html(status.status).css({ 'color': statusColor, 'font-weight': 'bolder' })
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex3Vr/)

Comment: No unfortunately that broke everything (and also did not change the period)

Comment: @LemonFlip Can you try the demo and update it as what you have.. It would really help to debug.

Comment: It is working fine in the code you have for the demo ... I'm starting to think it's relevant to the API we are working with. I'm going to say this is the correct answer though because this would probably work with other APIs.

Comment: @LemonFlip The best way is to narrow down where it is failing.. I think you need to `console.log` on each line to check where it is failing..

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript strings are immutable.  `.replace()` returns a new string you have to do something with.

```
var newStatus = $.trim(status.teamCityProject
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/ /g, "_")
    .replace(/\./g, '_')) + status.id;
// do something with newStatus
```

Comment: I was having an issue that I had completely overlooked in the beginning stages of development until I did a test for the Band name W.A.S.P., and the search results would return anything that had "W" in the name. So, having the period change to an underscore did the trick. Thank you, Jimbo.

Answer (score 1):

What you have [works](http://jsfiddle.net/BDZWK/).

However, you can condense this into a single `replace()` and avoid `String` with the following. Also note that your original post was missing the closing `)` for `trim()`.

```
$.trim((status.teamCityProject).toLowerCase().replace(/[ .]/g, "_") + status.id);
```

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ELyAD/2/).

Comment: With yours I get this string back (which is turned into a table row id)
    tr id="petersonfarms.shopfloorbt13"

Comment: Bad, as the period is still not an underscore

Comment: My guess is something is wrong with your input. All of these examples have working demos.